# Is it possible to have multi colored templated string in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string defined as

```
<string name="info_detail">Info - %1$s</string>
```

I would like to have "Info -" to be of black and bold color and the placeholder to be a light gray.

I also tried

```
<string name="info_detail"><font fgcolor="#000000">Info - </font><font fgcolor="#00FF00">%1$s</font></string>
```

with

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.info).text = Html.fromHtml(String.format(getString(R.string.info_detail), info), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS)
```

But they are not updating with either color and when I `println` I just see the raw string without formatting applied before and after using `Html.fromHtml`

Is there a way to do this in android without having to break out the template and split the TextView into multiple TextView's in order to have different colors? I have many other fields that I would like to format also.

I'm new to Android, so really also wondering what the correct way to do this is without having to just hardcode strings or html into the code.

Comment: You wouldn't see the color with println.  Println is a log-  it doesn't keep color info and doesn't have color capability.  Println is a debugging tool, not something you use for actual output.  You would see it if you put it in a TextView, because the actual string is a spannable string with ColorSpannables in it.

Comment: And try using color= instead of fgcolor= in the html tag

Comment: `getString()` will remove all formatting. You need to use `getText()`, which in turn does not work with `String.format()`. You might try using `TextUtils.replace()` instead of `String.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know formats doesnt work with println. But for textview you can do it with spannable strings.

**here is a kotlin example**

```
val spannableString = SpannableString(getString(R.string.myText))
spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)), 0, 5, 0)

findViewById<TextView>(R.id.info).text = spannableString
```

first 0 is first index of your "red" color starts. 5 is where it ends.

**dynamic text example:**

```
val spinText = SpannableString(safeContext.getString(R.string.placeholder_order_item_id, id))
spinText.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(safeContext, R.color.green)), spinText.indexOf(id), spinText.indexOf(id) + id.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
binding.tvLeftTitle.text = spinText
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't as dynamic as I wanted, this is still dependent on knowing the length of your string.

Comment: you can divide the string as dynamic and static parts. than you get the start.index and length of string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how acceptable it is but I accomplished it by doing

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_field).text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_field, text), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

and in my strings.xml I have

```
    <string name="text_field">&lt;font color="#aaaaaa">&lt;b>Text is - &lt;/b>%1$s&lt;/font></string>
```

Docs have an example similar to above
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

I was getting tripped up with having to escape the right angle bracket with `&lt;`